# Is there a way to place JButtons with different spaces in the begining at the GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjqaD.png]

But I can't leave spaces before the buttons. I have tried to add invisible buttons, but nothing has changed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameSize; i++ ){
        c.gridwidth = (i+1)*2;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4*i;
        JRadioButton temp = new JRadioButton();
        temp.setVisible(false);
        board.add(temp,c);
        for(int j = 0; j < gameSize; j++){
            c.gridwidth = 4;
            c.gridx = 2+(4*j);
            c.gridy = 2+(4*i);
            cells[i][j] = new JButton();
            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
            board.add(cells[i][j],c); 
        }
    }
```

It's look like [this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFoz9.png]

when I made them visible. I didn't get why width of them is still 4 even though I'm assigning it to (i+1)*2.

I'm new to Java and very very new to Java GUI. So, maybe I didn't figure out the most basic thing. Thanks for advices!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65965772/jbutton-in-jpanel-with-gridlayout

Comment: You will probably have to make each button take two columns in the GridLayout.

Comment: You could also nest layouts, gridbags within gridbags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following GUI.

[image: Staggered Layout]

In order to do this, I had to use a combination of Swing layouts.

The buttons on each row are created in a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`.  The row is created with a row `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout`, using a dummy `JLabel` and the button row `JPanel`.

The main `JPanel` uses a `GridLayout` of (0, 1) to create the staggered effect.  The dummy `JLabel` in each row gets bigger by half the size of the `JButtons`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutStaggeredGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutStaggeredGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Staggered Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        int gameSize = 8;
        int buttonSize = 50;
        int inset = 2;
        JButton[][] cells = new JButton[gameSize][gameSize];
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < gameSize; i++) {
            JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(
                    new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0));
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(inset, buttonSize));
            innerPanel.add(label);
            innerPanel.add(createRowPanel(cells[i], buttonSize));   
            
            panel.add(innerPanel);
            
            inset += buttonSize / 2;
        }
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createRowPanel(JButton[] cells, int buttonSize) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, cells.length, 0, 0));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i] = new JButton();
            cells[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            cells[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonSize, buttonSize));
            panel.add(cells[i]);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GridBagLayout` can only calculate the width of a column if there is a component added to the column with a "gridwidth" of 1.

In your example you have 6 button each with a "gridwidth" of 2, implying you really want 12 columns. But what should the width of each column be?

The example below shows how to allocate a minimum width for each column. Now each of the 12 columns will have a minimum width based on the value specified.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class GridBagLayoutMRE extends JPanel
{
    public GridBagLayoutMRE()
    {
        int gameSize = 6;
        int columnsNeeded = (gameSize * 3);
        int cellSize = 30;
        Dimension buttonSize = new Dimension(cellSize * 2, cellSize);

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout( gbl );

        int[] columnWidths = new int[columnsNeeded];
        Arrays.fill(columnWidths, cellSize);
        gbl.columnWidths = columnWidths;

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        for (int i = 0; i < gameSize; i++)
        {
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = i;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;

            JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton();
            rb.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(60, cellSize) );
            add(rb, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = i + 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;

            for (int j = 0; j < gameSize; j++)
            {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                button.setPreferredSize( buttonSize );
                add(button, gbc);

                gbc.gridx = gbc.gridx + gbc.gridwidth;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutMRE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        frame.add(new GridBagLayoutMRE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```